# SpectralNorm gets cancelled when followed by BatchNorm?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-network, batch-normalization

I am implementing a version of [FastGAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.04775), and it seems like (see the [official repo](https://github.com/odegeasslbc/FastGAN-pytorch/blob/main/models.py#L231)) they use a [Spectral norm](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/utils/spectral_norm.html) directly followed by a [Batch norm.](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm2d.html) Doesn't the spectral norm get fully cancelled by the following Batch Norm?

I believe it does, and have coded up a simple demonstration, could someone please confirm I am not missing something basic and that indeed the authors made a mistake?

### The reasoning

- Spectral normalization takes a linear operator `O` and rescales it by it's inverse spectral norm `1 / sigma(O)`
- Batch norm (without learnable `beta`,`gamma`) effectively shifts and scales the operator after which it is applied: `BN(O(x)) = (O(x) - E[O(x)]) / (std[O(x)])`

  - so `BN(k*O(x)) = (O(x))` for any inputs `x` and factor `k`

### My simple demonstration:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
# BatchNormed Convolution
conv = nn.Conv2d(3,1,3,1,0, bias=False)
c_dict = dict(conv.named_parameters())
c_dict["weight"].data = torch.ones_like(c_dict["weight"].data)
bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(1, affine=False)

# BatchNormed SpectralNormed
conv2 = nn.Conv2d(3,1,3,1,0, bias=False)
c_dict = dict(conv2.named_parameters())
c_dict["weight"].data = torch.ones_like(c_dict["weight"].data)

# Spectral Normalize the 2nd conv
sn_conv = spectral_norm(conv2)

bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(1, affine=False)

# Now feed an image into both conv & sn_conv
im = torch.randn(size=(2,3,4,4))
cim = conv(im)
sncim = sn_conv(im)

bn1.train()
bn2.train()

# Feed the conv & sn_conv outputs through their batchnorm 1000 times
for i in range(1000):
    cimbn = bn1(cim)
    sncimbn = bn2(sncim)

assert torch.isclose(cimbn, sncimbn)
>>> Gives the same result
```

I believe the only effective difference between the two (BN(SN(Conv)) & BN(Conv)) is that they will get initialized to slightly different functions?

Comment: I can’t be bothered to read all that code for the spectral norm. If it’s a linear transformation of the values, then yes, it is pointless to do that before normalizing the mean and standard deviation.